# System wide Alerts wtihout Push Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to create a notification or alert in iOS without using push notificatons?

For instance, at a given time, say 8:00 p.m. I would want to create a notification (like a push notification) on the user's lock screen.

Or, in another case, I would want to create an alert, if the user is using their device at 8:00 p.m. that would appear right in front of them!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, I think you want to use Local notifications as opposed to Push notifications. "Push" notifications are pushed from a server, and require either a server on your end, or use of a service like Urban Airship. "Local" Notifications can be done entirely on the device, without any other services getting involved.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html